# Открыть один элемент, закрывать другой

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такая HTML конструкция:

```
    <div class="open_case_field_wrap">
            <input type="text" value=""><span class="help_wrap"><span class="help_icon">?</span><span class="help_text">ТЕКСТ 1</span></span>
   </div>
   <div class="open_case_field_wrap">
        <textarea name="desc"></textarea><span class="help_wrap"><span class="help_icon">?</span><span class="help_text">ТЕКСТ 2</span></span>
   </div>
```

И такой jquery

```
$('.help_icon').click(function() {
        $(this).parent('.help_wrap').toggleClass('help_info_open');
    });
```

Как дописать js, чтобы если у одного .help_wrap добавлен класс help_info_open (блок открывается стилями), а нажали на другой, то этот закрывается, а другой открывается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно модифицировать только скрипт, то так можно например.

```js
$('.help_icon').click(function() {
  $('.help_info_open').not($(this).parent()).removeClass('help_info_open');
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('help_info_open');
});
```

```css
.help_wrap>.help_text {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.help_info_open>.help_text {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="open_case_field_wrap">
  <input type="text" value="">
  <span class="help_wrap">
    <span class="help_icon">?</span>
  <span class="help_text">ТЕКСТ 1</span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="open_case_field_wrap">
  <textarea name="desc"></textarea>
  <span class="help_wrap">
    <span class="help_icon">?</span>
  <span class="help_text">ТЕКСТ 2</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю. То что нужно, а то я в какие-то дебри с parent, each, но нужного эффекта добиться не получилось. "Если нужно модифицировать только скрипт" - а вы что-то еще исправить хотели?

Comment: @Aaron мне показалась неудобной текущая верстка и работа с ней, но это субъективщина

Comment: всегда открыт к предложениям и корректировкам в лучшую сторону. Как бы вы изменили?